# MIddleware not working properly in prod environment

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, pinia

I'm building a simple app with a login based on a user cookie, user fills out form and submits to set cookie and allow access to protected routes. On initial app mount I check for cookie and sync with pinia store and if not authenticated and page is not login redirect back to login. All working as expected locally but in production environment after login and reload it redirects back to login even if authenticated. I checked for errors and none, also cookie is showing as active and still redirects back to login on page refresh. not sure where I could be going wrong?

middleware - auth.global.ts

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();  
  authStore.syncCookieState();

  if (!authStore.isAuthenticated && to.path !== '/login') {
    return navigateTo('/login');
  }
});
```

pinia store

```
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: 'auth-store',
  state: () => {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: false,
    };
  },
  actions: {
    syncCookieState() {
      const userCookie = useCookie('user-auth');
      this.isAuthenticated = !!userCookie.value;
    },
  },
});
```

form submit , set cookie

```
async function onSubmit(event: FormSubmitEvent<any>) {
  const userCookie = useCookie('user-auth', { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 });
  userCookie.value = 'usertoken';

}
```